# Update info in section header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a custom UIView for the section header in my UITableView. However, when I make changes to the table view, the labels in the section header are not updated until the user attempts to scroll. Does anyone know why this is? And how I can update the section header immediately? If it helps, I am using Core Data, and my project is based on Apple's Core Data Books example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call reloadData on your tableView after updating the section header.

Comment: Thank you!! Can you explain why this works? Are changes to the table view not displayed until `reloadData` is called?

Comment: Unless you implemented NSFetchedResultsController, changes to your data source do not automatically update your tableview.

Comment: But if I am implementing NSFetchedResultsController, would this be the most efficient way to update the section header?